# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given - Laravel Error Mailer

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am using laravel mailer for sending mail. but it gives me this error.
Please can you get me out of this? Thanks in Advance.

This is the controller part.

```
DB::table('email')->insert([
            ['subject' => $subject, 'message' => $messages, 'sent_to' => $to_email, 'patient' => $patient_id, 'file' => $target_file]
        ]);

Mail::send('emails.mail', ['message' => $messages], function($message) use ($to_email) {
            $message->to($to_email)
            ->subject($subject);
            $message->from('physical.org','TestMail');
        });
```

Now, this is mail.blade.php

```
{{ $message }}
```

Comment: And the insert query runs perfectly and stores the message as a string.

Comment: Hi Bryan, could you please add the whole stack-trace of this issue to the question? This helps pin-point whats happening.